# Using CSS with a JSP in Spring Web MVC Application

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to figure out how to use an external css file which is stored in my resources folder for my jsp page.  I have so far tried a few different things based off research and have not found a solution yet.

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ProjectX</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/homepage.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The message of the day is:</h1>
    <p>${titleHomepage}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

servletConfig.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7rRR.png)

I also believe its a better structure to place my resource files inside src/man/resources which I also tried to play around with but got the same results as the problem above.

SOLUTION FOUND:

[Full Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YihDA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that my maven project is pulling the files I needed to use from my WebContent folder instead of src/main/webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You having your resource folder at wring place.

Put it in `webapp` folder directly insted of `webapp/WEB-INF/resources` or
change path in `servletConfig.xml`. Better way is to move folder out side of the `WEB-INF`

Comment: So I am kind of confused by your comment.  You say to put my resources folder inside the webapp folder but not webapp/resources?  I have relocated my resources folder so it now resides within webapp and not WEB-INF but still cannot access CSS files.

Comment: That was just a mistake while typing..... Sorry. Have you redeployed and restarted your server? And what is the error that you are getting in console of browser?

Comment: I also noticed that I have a WEB-INF folder located in src/main/webapp and another WEB-INF folder located inside WebContent folder.  I am not sure the different and which one I should be using.

Comment: if you are using `Maven` then probably it should be `webapp` folder only.
Can you show full structure of your project

Comment: It was my structure.  For some reason my project is using my WebContent folder for its resources, servlets, and pages.  I will update a screenshot of my folder structure above.